# checkboxes wont align to the right

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, right-align

Ive got a custom CheckBox widget where it returns a label and a checkbox field,

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Text(widget.label, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
      Checkbox(
        activeColor: LightSeaGreen,
        checkColor: White,
        value: _checkbox,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _checkbox = !_checkbox;
          });
          widget.onChanged(value);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

So right now,It looks like this,

[image]

what I want is for the checkboxes to align to the right like this

[image]

Ive tried the Align fuction,Spacer,MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween but nothing works

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try Spacer to put space in between:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text(widget.label, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
      Spacer(),
      Checkbox(
        activeColor: LightSeaGreen,
        checkColor: White,
        value: _checkbox,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _checkbox = !_checkbox;
          });
          widget.onChanged(value);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. you can used `Spacer()` widget for that and I think `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` is also working

Refer CheckBox documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html)

Refer Spacer class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)

Refer Layoutes [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Declare bool variable:

```
bool isChecked = false;
```

Your Widget:

```
 Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Row(
        //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text('widget.label',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
          Spacer(),
          Checkbox(
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            checkColor: Colors.white,
            value: isChecked,
            onChanged: (bool? value) {
              setState(() {
                isChecked = value!;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen Without check -> [image]

Your result screen With check -> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  body:
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(child:Text("Text", style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4)),
        Checkbox(
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          checkColor: Colors.blue,
          value: false,
          onChanged: (value) {
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
);
```

Comment: I get this error RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.

Comment: Updated my answer, Check now

Comment: now in the ui the checkbox aint visible at all , an it says right overflowed by infinity pixels

Comment: Replace your whole build method with this and check, not just inner code

Comment: thats how I did it .This is the error I get  "RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout."

Comment: I have checked it and it works completely fine I request you to create one new screen and then replace whole build method in that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line and try `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max
    children: [
      Text(widget.label, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
      Checkbox(
        activeColor: LightSeaGreen,
        checkColor: White,
        value: _checkbox,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _checkbox = !_checkbox;
          });
          widget.onChanged(value);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: still wont align

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code

[image]

[image]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          title: const Text(
            'label',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          autofocus: false,
          activeColor: Colors.blue,
          checkColor: Colors.white,
          selected: _checkbox,
          value: _checkbox,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              _checkbox = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what i see people have answered you use the spacer that can one solution. But Just from my thinking I would suggest you.

1. So initially what you do is Add the container as a parent to this widget and give a color and check if the color is just covering the child widget. It means that the space between parameter would not work because it is expanding as max as parent widget.
2. So to use the max width you can use a MediaQuery  or use the Layoutbuilder widget to get the device width and height

I have Added an Example below how this works.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String label = "NVD";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          
          // this is when the parent has a full width
          Container(// consider container as parent 
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(label, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
                      Checkbox(
                        activeColor: Colors.grey,
                        checkColor: Colors.white,
                        value: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    height: 10,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          
          // this is when the below container which is parent and has 
          // specific width due to which child is will adjust accordingly.
          Container(
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(label, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
                      Checkbox(
                        activeColor: Colors.grey,
                        checkColor: Colors.white,
                        value: true,
                        onChanged: (value) {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 10,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Image for the code implentation
[image]

Let me know if it works

Thanks.